# How to extract a context from an URL before reaching the route engine in Web API 2 + Attribute Routing?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I'm migrating a web service from pure C# / no framework to Web API 2. This web service exposes  Movies objects (with properties like title, actors, plot...) and these movies objects contains   VideoContents objects. These VideoContents objects are associated to a device and/or a specific SiteInstance (think of it as a catalog for example).

I have to follow a specific URL model which is :

/api/movies/1234 = returns the movie #1234 with all of its contents
/api/{device}/movies/1234 = returns the movie #1234 with only the contents matching this device
/api/{device}/{siteInstance}/movies/1234 = returns the movie #1234 with only the contents matching this device and this siteInstance.

I made a first version with "traditionnal" routing, I had 3 routes defined :

```
"api/{controller}/{id}"
"api/{device}/{controller}/{id}"
"api/{device}/{instance}/{controller}/{id}"
```

And I used a IAutofacActionFilter to hook the request, extract the context and inject it in my controller. It worked well !

Now, I want to migrate to AttributeRouting because, well, it seems to be the "way to go" and I like the idea of the routeTemplate being near the method for future debugging ect... But I don't want to repeat 3 times my routes on each method of my web service, so I'm looking for a way to "intercept" the request before it goes to the route engine, extract my context, and returns the clean url to the route engine. Basically :

- Request done to /api/DeviceXYZ/movies/1234
- Request is intercepted, "DeviceXYZ" is extracted and Context object built / injected where it needs to be (my controller)
- /api/movies/1234 is sent to the route engine
- request is matched by the attributeRouting : [Route("api/movies/{id:int}")] and executed.

I'm looking forward to any ideas, even if it's not exactly the way I see it. I think this whole context parsing should not be done by the route engine but maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks !

Edit: I forgot to add that I don't want to see these parameters in my methods signatures. They are used to build a Context object which is injected in my controller constructor through Autofac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept every request of your service you can implement a custom message handler.

I use:

```
   HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://127.0.0.1");
 config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestInterceptor());
```

With a RequestInterceptor class defined as:

```
public class RequestInterceptor : DelegatingHandler
{
    public RequestInterceptor ()
    {
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Here you can do whatever you want to the request.
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This intercepts first before being routed.

Also, you may want to review Dependency injection http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver to handle device specific contexts.